# The word for "?!" or "!?"

Tags: punctuation

Is there a word for the punctuation "?!" or "!?"? A friend of mine steeped in such idiosyncrasies of eccentric English lore said there was but could not recall the name. I guess for reasons known only to the search-gods it seems rather ineffective to Google.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently it's an [interrobang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang).

Comment: +1.  Interrobang usually refers to an amalgamation of the two marks, but it indeed describes this phenomenon.  The actual interrobang mark is extremely rare, and may be completely absent from regular usage.

Comment: @Brendon If so, why was it given a Unicode codepoint‽

Comment: @DKrueger:  The Unicode codepoint set is pretty comprehensive, so it's not surprising that it contains a character that is only rarely used.  I've never seen the symbol in use, other than on the aforementioned article.

Comment: Unicode is intentionally almost absurdly comprehensive. It also has the irony mark. Isn't *that* just the most useful thing⸮

Comment: By my reading of the Unicode Consortium's rules, a **huge** chunk of Unicode code points are explicitly not supposed to be there (i.e. their presence clashes with the stated purpose of Unicode), but they are :/

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That emoticon should be: 